# Info Windows not showing up on Markers with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making markers & info windows using an 'each' loop with jQuery to iterate over elements of the DOM. I defined a global infomarker variable, according to the Maps API, this is the way to make it so that only one infomarker appears at a time. Currently, clicking on the markers does nothing. Oddly, there is a spot around the center of the map that I can click on to bring up an infomarker (with content that attaches it to one of the markers). Any idea what I can do to fix this?

```
$(function () {
  function initialize() {

    // Get city coordinates .. set map options so map centers on city .. place map on map-canvas  
    var page_city_lat = $("#page_city_lat").text();
    var page_city_lng = $("#page_city_lng").text();
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(page_city_lat, page_city_lng),
      zoom: 10
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    // define concert object, mapCoords
    function Concert(x)
    {
      this.lat = $(x).find(".lat").text();
      this.lng = $(x).find(".lng").text();    
      this.headline = $(x).find(".event_title").text();
      this.venue = $(x).find(".venue").text();
      this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng)
    };


    // Global infowindow variable declaration makes only 1 infowindow open at a time. 
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}); 
    // Necessary to pre-declare variable?
    var map_ids = $(".map_id");
    $.each(map_ids, function (index, value) 
    {
      var listing = new Concert(value);
      var concertString = 'headline: ' + listing.headline + '<br>' + 'Venue' + listing.venue
      var concertMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
      {
        position: listing.latlng,
        map: map,
        title: listing.venue
      });
      infowindow.setContent(concertString);
      google.maps.event.addListener(concertMarker, 'click', function () {
          infowindow.open(map, concertMarker);    
      });
    });
  };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work as expected, but he works somehow for me(the infoWindow opens when I click on a marker), so you should post more details or a demo to be able to identify the main-issue(after that we may talk about the other issues, e.g. the spot).

Comment: @Dr.Molle unfortunately i encountered problems getting the map on heroku but hope to do that soon. Until then, if you can run rails apps, you can duplicate the issue by cloning the most recent commit on the master branch of github.com/maxpleaner/data_streams

Comment: @Dr.Molle sorry, I forgot to give the url to get to the page if you load the app... it's localhost:3000/map/index?city=oakland or you can enter in a different city

Comment: localhost? It's april 3rd, not april 1th :D

Comment: @Dr.Molle remember I said I encountered problems getting it on Heroku? Also, I mentioned that you should use localhost _if_ you can run rails apps? Regardless, I have it online for the time being at http://7b61045c.ngrok.com/map/index?city=oakland (for the hosted code, see github.com/maxpleaner/datastreams master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please implement your code at jsfiddle.net so that we can verify the issue.

Check with below working code. Hope you get some idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        Google Maps Example
</title>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var infowindow = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initialize();
        }
                                         );

        function initialize() {

            var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -98.5795);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: centerMap,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        setMarkers(map, sites);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "loading..."
        }
                                                                                     );

        var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
        bikeLayer.setMap(map);
    }

var sites = [
['Delhi', 29.45155, 79.00268, 4, 'This is Delhi.'],
        ['Badlands National Park', 43.785890, -101.90175, 1, 'This is Badlands National Park']
    ];



function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4]
        }
                                                                             );

        var contentString = "Some content";

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //alert(this.html);
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        }
                                                                 );
    }
}
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```